# "If true propensity score is constant, then the superpopulation covariate distributions are identical in two treatment groups"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, conditional-expectation, propensity-scores

This is a statement made in Rubin's Causal Inference Sec 12.5.1. I would take it under assumption of unconfoundedness framework.

"If the superpopulation covariate distributions are identical in two treatment groups, then true propensity score must be constant and vice versa."

Consider unconfounded experiment. Let $f(W|X,Y(0),Y(1))$ be conditional distribution of treatment $W$($W=0$ control group or $W=1$ treatment group) conditioned upon covariate $X$ and outcomes $Y(0),Y(1)$. Propensity score by definition is $e(X)=E_{sp}[f(W=1|X,Y(0),Y(1))|X]$ where subscript $sp$ means expectation taken over super population.

By unconfoundedness(generally assumed and not testable), $f(W|X,Y(0),Y(1))=f(W|X)$. $e(X)=E_{sp}[f(W=1|X)|X]$ which is a function of $X$ only. Assume $f(X|W=1)=f(X|W=0)$.(By assumption, covariate distributions is same in two groups.) This gives $W\perp X$ independence which guarantees $f(W=1|X)=f(W=1)$. Thus $e(X)=E_{sp}[f(W=1)|X]=f(W=1)$.

How do I see "vice versa" part? In other words, $e(X)=E_{sp}[f(W=1|X)|X]$ constancy implies $f(W=1|X)$ constancy.(This would allow previous argument running backwards.) Somehow, I would expect that for any $f(W=1|X)$ non constancy, I can find some $x,y$ s.t. $E_{sp}[f(W=1|X)|X=x]\neq E_{sp}[f(W=1|X)|X=y]$.

I do not recall measure theoretic statement on $E[X|Y]$ being constant implies $X$ being constant in general. That is why I have doubt in "vice versa" part.

Comment: Why do you have $e(X) = E_{sp}[f(W=1|X)|X]$ instead of just $e(X) = f(W=1|X)$, which is the usual definition of the propensity score?

Comment: @Noah I took Rubin's super population propensity score definition(3.7 of the book) in super population model. I think in your case, you need to assume individualist assumption here which allows $e(x)=f(W=1|x)$.

Comment: In that same section he says $e(x) = Pr(W=1|X=x)$. There is no assumption; it's just iterated expectations.

Comment: What about page 40, "Note that with our definition of super-populations the assignment mechanism is automatically individualistic"

Comment: @Noah I think you are right on that. There are two propensity scores one in Def 3.3(pg 35) as finite population propensity score and the other one in Def 3.7(pg 39) superpopulation propensity score. Which one is used here?

Comment: I would guess based on context he is talking about the superpopulation propensity score since he is talking about the superpopulation distribution of covariates.

Comment: @Noah I see. Then the statement follows easily. Thanks.